# What are enums for in Java?

Tags: java, enums

What is the advantage of using enums over ints? I'm trying to represent the suits in a card game, and I thought 1,2,3,4 would be good enough. But my boss says I need to do it with enums. Why?

Comment: What suit maps to 1? Not very intuitive. If I define an enum with suits `SPADES` etc, much more readable.

Comment: 1. meaningful names, 2. they are also classes in their own right, with methods. Consider `TimeUnit`: `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10L)`

Comment: [Type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety)!

Answer (score 1):

Enums are good because they remove "magic numbers"- numbers that don't really mean anything on their own. By replacing those numbers with actual values, your code makes more sense and follows better design principles.

Also, enums prevent incorrect values from being passed to a function. If your enum only defines `Spades, Hearts, Clubs`, and `Diamonds`, then only objects of the enum can be passed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `int`s, then what does the suit `5` mean?  You'll have to handle that case.  What if a caller sees `int` and accidentally passes `2` attempting to create a "deuce"?  Just using `int`s, the same number may represent more than one valid, different value in different domains.

It is more typesafe to use an enum.  It can only have your own pre-defined values, and the different type name disallows accidentally passing a valid value from another domain to your restricted domain of values.

Answer (score 1):

`enum` in java provides compile time check. So if you pass `100` in your program it will compile but fail at run time. An `enum` will make sure this does not happen.